# ContainerSelectionDialog in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I develop my first plugin - 2 questions:

1. I'm using ContainerSelectionDialog dialog in my eclipse plugin to give my user the option to choose project.
   but it show me the project and the folder in them, I want to show the user only the project with out option to expend the project and choose folder,
   how can I do it?
2. when user select my wizard (new->other->myWizard) i want to know which project in the packageexplorer it select ( like you have in new class that it know which project is selectd)

Thanks!!

Comment: You should split this up into two separate questions. #2 is most likely answered already in StackOverflow, so try searching first.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.ElementListSelectionDialog` and call `setElements()` on it. The data you pass to `setElements()` should be an array of `IProject` instances; one way to obtain that is via `org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects()`

*Note A:* `IWorkspaceRoot.getProjects()` will return all projects, including closed ones, so depending on your needs you may want to filter that list before passing it to the dialog (look at `IProject.isAccessible()`)

*Note B:* You can use `org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchLabelProvider.getDecoratingWorkbenchLabelProvider()` for the dialog's labelProvider.

Comment: thanks, i don't see documentation about IProject.isAccessible()), how can I use it, and what this funvtion return?